# How to customize depth Graph of amcharts?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, amcharts

I am trying to customize the depth graph **amchart** but I'm unable to understand it. How it works how to style it as an image that given below?

**Here is the link of the original graph which I want to customizing it**

[Link](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/live-order-book-depth-chart/)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information, what you want to achieve? Maybe some code, you are working on and where you need help with.

Comment: Samuel sir I just need this graph https://www.amcharts.com/demos/live-order-book-depth-chart/ in above graph as shown in Figure I just want to customize it i don't get how to customize it Thanks

Comment: Please provide some code, e.g. a code pen, because it is very difficult to help you without knowing what you actually have.

Comment: Thanks Now issue resolved here is solution ishttps://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/9801ece19a15b7f3c72c5b6af501bcb9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please think about the person answering your question, you say "customize" but that could mean anything, please be as specific as possible so people can help you.

That said, the guides and demos on amCharts are fairly comprehensive, and we're still building on them, so suggestions are welcome especially if there's something essential that feels missing.

If you're looking to customize the colors of the chart, you can use CSS to change the background of the entire chart as is done in this [demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/map-line-chart-gauge/):

```css
#chartdiv {
  background-color:#121212;
}
```

It also shows how to disable the grid line if you're interested in that:

```js
axis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
```

[You can disable other axis elements like their labels similarly (this link is part of a larger guide on Axes in general)](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/#Disabling_certain_elements).

If you want to customize colors, first [refer to our guide on colors](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/colors/) as you'll be using JavaScript to color SVGs as opposed to CSS. Usually the attributes for SVGs through which colors will be applied are their `fill` and `stroke` attributes. While you *can* use keyword, hex, and rgb strings, on some rare occasions, this may then lose out on the colors animating between states. So if it's not a problem, try and use the `am4core.Color` class (the `am4core.color` is a convenience method to generate an instance of `Color`, please note the difference in upper/lower case).

To adjust the colors of the plot area, [there is a default `plotContainer` property on XYCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/svg-engine/containers/#Pre_defined_chart_containers), you can assign a `fill` to its first child's `background` property, e.g.:

```js
chart.plotContainer.children.getIndex(0).background.fill = am4core.color({ r: 17, g: 27, b: 54 }).brighten(0.2);
```

For alternating colors, please see our guide ["Alternating axis fills"](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/alternated-axis-fills/).

To flip the axes, just swap the x/y axes, i.e. instead of the variables `xAxis` and `yAxis` in the original demo you linked to, I've changed them to `valueAxis` on the x axis and `categoryAxis` on the y axis (changing instances of `{categoryX}` to `{categoryY}` and `{valueX}` to `{valueY}`, speaking of which if you're looking to customize labels and tooltips' text, you can learn about [formatting strings in v4](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/)). This will stand the chart up so it's from bottom->up, left aligned. If you want the chart to be anchored to the right, set the x [axis renderer's `inversed` property](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/axisrenderer/#inversed_property) to `true`:

```js
valueAxis.renderer.inversed = true;
```

Here's a fork of your demo with much of the above combined:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/9801ece19a15b7f3c72c5b6af501bcb9

Comment: Thank you So much Notacouch.I really appreciate your help and effort Once again thanks issue Solved.

Comment: @ZubairSaif You're welcome! If the answer was sufficient for you, please accept it as the best answer by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows.